# flutter laravel websockets Private Channel trigger current location

Tags: laravel, flutter, websocket, location, channel

i have **laravel** and set up the **websockets** and all is good
and in my **flutter** app i connect to websockets private channel and its good
but here is the bug is that i listen to the server events
but i need the app to send data to channel and let all users on same channel see the data
the flutter dont **(trigger)** data on channel
**(the delivery boy send his current location to the channel and the customer listen to the delivery location that updated)**

**The Flutter Code**

```
import 'package:pusher_client/pusher_client.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DeliveryLocationTrackingProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late Channel _channel;

  // the user's initial location and current location
  // as it moves
  late LocationData _currentLocation;
  // wrapper around the location API
  late Location _location;

  Location get location => this._location;
  LocationData get currentLocation => this._currentLocation;

  set location(Location location) {
    this._location = location;
  }

  set currentLocation(LocationData currentLocation) {
    this._currentLocation = currentLocation;
  }

  late PusherClient pusher;
  late Channel channel;
  late PusherOptions pusherOptions;
  //
  connectToPusher() {
    PusherAuth auth = PusherAuth(
      'http://shahwanji.com/broadcasting/auth',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${SharedManager.shared.token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    );

    pusherOptions = PusherOptions(
      host: '*********.com',
      wsPort: 6001,
      encrypted: false,
      auth: auth,
    );

    pusher = PusherClient(
      '****************',
      pusherOptions,
      enableLogging: true,
    );

    pusher.connect();

    pusher.onConnectionStateChange((state) {
      print("currentState: ${state?.currentState} -- -- ");
    });

    pusher.onConnectionError((error) {
      print("error: ${error?.message}");
    });
  }

  disconnectFromPusher() {
    // // Disconnect from pusher service
    pusher.disconnect();
  }

  Future<Channel> connectToChannel(String channelName) async {
    await this.connectToPusher();

    return pusher.subscribe(channelName);
  }
  // ////////

  listenToMove() async {
    // create an instance of Location
    this._location = new Location();

    // set the initial location by pulling the user's
    // current location from the location's getLocation()
    this._currentLocation = await this._location.getLocation();

    // subscribe to changes in the user's location
    // by "listening" to the location's onLocationChanged event

    this._connect();

    this._location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData cLoc) {
      //   // cLoc contains the lat and long of the
      //   // current user's position in real time,
      //   // so we're holding on to it
      this._currentLocation = cLoc;
      print("cLoc.latitude ${cLoc.latitude}");
      _channel.trigger('client-update-location', {
        'the-data-latitude': cLoc.latitude,
        'the-data-longitude': cLoc.longitude,
      });

      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  _connect() async {
    this._channel = await connectToChannel(
        'private-delivery.${SharedManager.shared.delivery.id}');
  }

  listenLocation() async {
    await this._connect();

    this._channel.bind("update-location", (PusherEvent? event) {
      print("update-location update-location ${event?.data}");
      _channel.trigger('client-update-location',
          {'the-data-latitude': 0.0, 'the-data-longitude': 0.0});
    });

    _channel.bind("pusher:subscription_succeeded", (PusherEvent? event) {
      _channel.trigger('client-update-location',
          {'the-data-latitude': 0.0, 'the-data-longitude': 0.0});
      print('event.data ${event?.data}');
    });
  }
}
```

**Laravel Code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events\Delivery;

use App\Models\Delivery;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TrackDeliveryLocationEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public Delivery $delivery;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Delivery $delivery)
    {
        $this->delivery = $delivery;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('delivery.' . $this->delivery->id);
    }

    // the event name we listion to
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'update-location';
    }

    // the data send with every send
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'the-data' => 'Hi In Test',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a relevant code snippet

Comment: okay and in the (debug console) it dont print any error

Comment: @SuperDJ here is the code